# Fade out background-image on unknown scroll height

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have a div with a background image. When the user scrolls the page, an opacity is added to the image so the second image appears. The effect is pretty nice if you add some style to the second image. I found the below script on http://mattduvall.com/blog/medium-ux-blurry-scroll/

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(window).height(),
        opacityVal = (s / 150.0);

    $('.second-image').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

However the image only changes after 150px scrolled which forces me to include this effect only on top positioned images. If an image is inserted on the middle of the page (> 150px) only the second image is dispayed and the effect lost.

I'm not a jQuery expert so I wonder if I can include a variable to add this effect when the image starts to "exit" the screen independent of the pixels scrolled.

What I want is to achieve the same effect however the pixels scrolled. I mean, if the image is on the top of the page, the effect will be shown the same as if on the bottom.

EDIT: Changed "blurred-image" class to the same as the fiddle. Fiddle created: http://jsfiddle.net/q6Qhm/

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be what you are looking for? I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        opacityVal = (s / $('.blurred-image').height());

    $('.blurred-image').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I worked with a long time ago.. 
part of it changes the opacity of the image untill it fades. 
I'd really like to help you but I dont have much time to edit my code, so I'll just paste the code part with some other less relevant stuff. Use the relevant parts.

I hope it will help you

```
window.onscroll = function (){
var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var image = document.getElementById('main_graph');
    var imageTop = document.getElementById('main_graph_top');
    var topButton = document.getElementById('top');
    var images_container = document.getElementById('images_container');
    if(scroll <= 1){
        opacity = 1;
        image.style.visibility = "visible";
        imageTop.style.visibility = "visible";
        images_container.style.zIndex=1001;
    }
    else if(scroll>1 && scroll <=212){
        opacity = 1 - (scroll / 212);
        image.style.visibility = "visible";
        imageTop.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else{
        var opacity = 0;
        image.style.visibility = "hidden";
        imageTop.style.visibility = "hidden";
        images_container.style.zIndex=900;
    }
    inverseOpacity = 1 - opacity;
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    imageTop.style.opacity = opacity;
    topButton.style.opacity = inverseOpacity;
}
```

Comment: Thans Hatul but can't find a way to implement your code with my needs.

Comment: If I'll have time later I'll try to help you and comment here :)